# "Polar opposite of someone" or "someone's polar opposite"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

As you know the term ["polar opposite"](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/polar-opposite-extreme) means "the complete or exact opposite of something else."
As far as I'm concerned, we can say something like: "we're polar opposites," but I need to know if we can call someone as "polar opposite of someone else" or "someone else's polar opposite".
I.e. may I know which sentence below is unnatural / unidiomatic English when it comes to someone who thinks exactly contrary to you / the other way around?

**a.** You're **the** polar opposite **of me**. 
**b.** You're **my** polar opposite.

Comment: Both are equally valid and natural.

Comment: You can say someone is "***the** polar opposite of someone else*", at least in North American-speak, "the" is required. I mention this because in the first example in the paragraph there's no "the".